# Certificate signature verification on Microchip PIC controllers

Tags: encryption, certificate, openssl, signature, verification

I'm trying to implement certificate signature verification on a Microchip pic controller (certificates are generated and signed using OpenSSL).  The Microchip PIC controller doesn't support OpenSSL libraries, but it does have an encryption/decryption function.  I was successful in getting a SSL connection between PIC controller and a web server.  My next step is to setup signature verification on the PIC controller.

After reading PKCS#1 V2.1 RSA Cryptography Standard (http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125)
I realized that encryption is essentially the same as signature verification and decryption is the same as signing.  More specifically both encryption and verification uses the public key and the following formula:

> m = s ^ e mod n

Where s is the signature or the message, e is the public exponent, n is the modulus and m is the encrypted message or decoded signature.  Therefore, I'm trying to use the encryption algorithm provided to perform signature verification.

In order to verify the certificate, I generated the SHA1 hash of the certificate; Decoded signature using CA's public key and encryption algorithm.  Remove the padding from the decoded signature, the result hash should be equal to the SHA1 hash of the certificate.

However, I cannot get the two hash values to be equal.  I tried to verify my assumption and PIC controller results using OpenSSL command line.

This is the hash value I got from both OpenSSL command line and PIC controller

> openssl rsautl -in signature.txt -verify -asn1parse -inkey pubkey.pem
>   -pubin
>   db e8 c6 cb 78 19 3c 0f-fd 96 1c 4f ed bd b2 34 45 60 bf 65

This is what I got from Signature verification using OpenSSL.  After removing "ff" paddings I'll end up with asn1 format of the certificate hash.

> openssl rsautl -verify -in signature.txt -inkey pubkey.pem -pubin
>   -raw -hexdump
>   00 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff-ff ff ff ff 00 30 21 30
>   09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a-05 00 04 14 **db e8 c6 cb
>
>   78 19 3c 0f fd 96 1c 4f-ed bd b2 34 45 60 bf 65**

However this is what I got from the PIC controller which is much different from the above

> 8e fb 62 0e 09 c8 0b 49 40 1f 4d 2d a7 7d d6 8c
>   9b bc 95 e6 bc 98 4b 96 aa 74 e5 68 90 40 bf 43
>   b5 c5 02 6d ab e3 ad 7b e6 98 fd 10 22 af b9 fb

This is my signature

> 7951 9b3d 244a 37f6 86d7 dc02 dc18 3bb4
>     0f66 db3a a3c1 a254 5be5 11d3 a691 63ef
>     0cf2 ec59 c48b 25ad 8881 9ed2 5230 bcd6

This is my public key (I'm using a very small key just for testing, will make it larger once everything works)

> 96 FE CB 59 37 AE 8C 9C 6C 7A 01 50 0F D6 4F B4
>      E2 EC 45 D1 88 4E 1F 2D B7 1E 4B AD 76 4D 1F F1
>      B0 CD 09 6F E5 B7 43 CA F8 14 FE 31 B2 06 F8 7B
>   Exponent is 01 00 01

I'm wondering are my assumptions wrong that I cannot use encryption algorithm for decoding signature?  or I'm doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the method I described above is correct. I was able to get the matching result from hashing the certificate and unsigning the signature using encryption.

The problem that caused my previous failing attempts was the endianess used by Microchip Pic controller.  They use small-endian instead of big-endian.  I did not pay attention to the endianness of the exponent since **01 00 01** is the same in either format.  However I was wrong, it turns out Microchip looks at a 4 byte value as the exponent (RSA standard??).  So it pads **00** in the front resulting **00 01 00 01**.  Therefore, the endianness matters now since **00 01 00 01** is different from **01 00 01 00**.  And **01 00 01 00** is the small-endian format that Microchip Pic uses.